# Ignore findbugs also ignores other

Tags: findbugs, spotbugs

Getting these bugs:

```
OPM_OVERLY_PERMISSIVE_METHOD
IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_NO_TOSTRING
PRMC_POSSIBLY_REDUNDANT_METHOD_CALLS
RI_REDUNDANT_INTERFACES
```

after adding this to findbugs-exclude.xml

```
<Match>
  <Not>
    <Bug code="IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_NO_TOSTRING"/>
  </Not>
</Match>
```

I no longer see any of the four listed bugs. I was only expecting IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_NO_TOSTRING to be ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `<Not>` operator, like so:

```xml
<Match>
  <Bug pattern="IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_NO_TOSTRING"/>
</Match>
```

The exclusion filter specifies what *not* to check, so the extra `Not` made it exclude everything except IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_NO_TOSTRING.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I did also try that, as that actually made more sense as this is an exclude file. 
Here is something from the documentation:
"<Not>
This element inverts the included child Match. I.e., you can put a Bug element in a Not clause in order to match any bug excluding the given one."

Comment: Removing the <Not> results in the IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_NO_TOSTRING is not ignored.

Comment: This is ignoring the IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_NO_TOSTRING from one specific class, and does NOT remove the other four bugs mentioned. 

<Match>
        <Or>
            <Class name="~.*\.LegDto"/>
        </Or>
        <Not>
            <Bug code="IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_NO_TOSTRING"/>
        </Not>
    </Match>

Comment: Updating to user Pattern instead of code:
<Match>
        <Bug pattern="IMC_IMMATURE_CLASS_NO_TOSTRING"/>
    </Match>
Solved the problem.

Comment: Funny, I also noticed the `code`/`pattern` thing, but since the documentation allows both if the full bug name is used, I thought the `<Not>` part must be the one. Updated answer.